Spark SQL Java error encoding the result of joining two Datasets using struct fields
I have two datasets, Dataset<A> and Dataset<B> that I want to join into a Dataset<C> where C is a class
class C {
    A a;
    B b;
}

I have joined them like this
Dataset<C> joinedRecords =
        A_records
            .as("A")
            .join(
                B_records.as("B"),
                functions
                    .col("A.uuid")
                    .equalTo(functions.col("B.uuid")),
                "inner")
            .withColumn("a", functions.struct("A.*"))
            .withColumn("b", functions.struct("B.*"))
            .select(
                functions.col("a"), functions.col("b"))
            .as(Encoders.bean(C.class));

But I get this error (can only show this much due to confidentiality) when I collect the dataset
Error while decoding: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
initializejavabean(newInstance(class 

Anyone see anything wrong with the way I am encoding? I have removed the encoding and it works with Row
